# How Can I display a partial view as part of another view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, partial-views

I want to display a partial view in Main View, Based on this ViewModel.
 The Main view use all models in ViewModel, but partial view use the first model.

```
public class EventManagementViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BPMSPARS.Models.DomainModels.CalendarEvent> Eventslist { get; set; }
    public BPMSPARS.Models.DomainModels.CalendarEvent Event { get; set; }
    public BPMSPARS.Models.DomainModels.EventsUser EventUser { get; set; }
}
```

in controller I have this code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Event()//partial view
    {
        EventManagementViewModel VM = new EventManagementViewModel();
        return PartialView(VM.Eventslist);
    }
    public ActionResult EventCalendar()//main view
    {
        EventManagementViewModel VM = new EventManagementViewModel();
        return View(VM);
    }
```

in mainview i have this code:

```
@model BPMSPARS.ViewModels.EventManagementViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
//..
<div>
@Html.Partial("Event",Model.Eventslist)
</div>
```

in partial view i have this code:

```
 @model IEnumerable<BPMSPARS.Models.DomainModels.CalendarEvent>
 <table class="table">
 <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventColor)
    </th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventColor)
    </td>
</tr>
 }
</table>
```

But when I run the main view i face this error:

*Message    "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'BPMSPARS.ViewModels.EventManagementViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BPMSPARS.Models.DomainModels.CalendarEvent]'."    string*

Do you know What should I do?
I think I must change the definition of models,on the other hand I don't how another definition is possible?
I search this topic But i don't find the exact problem that I faced it.

Comment: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Can you care to my problem?